# How to make an async call not prevent action from returning response to user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following async code

```
public async static void SendAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendException(ex, url);
    }
}
```

Which is called by the controller action.

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
// DO something 

SendAsync(some-valid-url);

// Do something

return View();
}
```

When i debug it - it runs async and hits

> return View();

and exits before it is comes to

> response.Close();

But in fiddler you can see that the http response is not sent by the browser and it waits for the SendAsync function to finish processing, which is not what i want. I want the http response to return back to the user right away.

What do I have to change here to achieve that?

Comment: You need to await the response from `SendAsync`. You should be getting a compiler warning [CS4014](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx) telling you that you forgot to do it.

Comment: When you use async /await  in your controller its work on server side and its not sense in client

Comment: i actually edited it and am now doing async static void since i do not need to track the end of the task and doing an await will make it wait for the async http call to finish. Which i do not want.

Comment: Be aware that your background work is not guaranteed to run in case of a worker process restart.

Comment: Looks like you are missing some key concepts of `async-await`. Have a look at my [async-await curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i actually edited it and am now doing async static void since i do not
>   need to track the end of the task,

But you do need to keep track, as MVC will close the connection when `Details` returns, you need to tell MVC you are waiting for a background action.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DetailsAsync(string id)
{
    // DO something 

    var sendTask = SendAsync(some-valid-url);

    // Do something else that does not depend on sendTask

    await sendTask;

    return View();
}
```

---

To answer your updated comment

> doing an await will make it wait for the async http call to finish.
>   Which i do not want.

To get the behavior you are looking for you need to use [AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the async/await system will not give you what you want by itself. (I have never really done MVC with AJAX so I don't have a example for you how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

> doing an await will make it wait for the async http call to finish.
>   Which i do not want.

It sounds to me like you want `fire and forget` since you don't want to wait for the response.

There are a few negative points to bare in mind (such as no error handling, no guarantees, etc), so I would recommend reading into this a bit before dropping it into your project.

This is, in my opinion, is the easiest way to call a method with `fire and forget`.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => SendAsync(some-valid-url));
```

This will request an available thread from the app pool. It will then use that thread to execute the  method without blocking your current running one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have been using threadpool.queueuserworkitem before, but that spawns new threads. I wanted to use async instead, to prevent spawning new threads for each of the requests.

Comment: The only way you can processes two things at the same time is with multiple threads. The async stuff just gives the worker thread back to the app pool while it waits for a result coming back. This allows the thread to be used elsewhere. You said you don't want to wait for the call to finish, async will still wait for http call to respond before continuing.

Comment: @MoXplod, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` manages worker threads and doesn't spawn any new ones if it doesn't absolutely have to. However, @Heymega, ASP.NET will not keep track of this and the application pool might be recycled at any point without having completed the work.